# use redis and mongodbb get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

when the spring-boot-starter-data-redis and spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb in my project I get

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException No qualifying bean of type
>   'com.comup.ownsite.authserver.repository.UserRepository' available

My spring boot version is 2.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: is `UserRepository` annotated with `@Repository` at the beginning?

Comment: Can you provide code of `UserRepository`?

Comment: public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String> {
    Optional<User> findFirstByUsername(String username);
}          when I annotated with @Repository I get the same exception

Answer (score 1):

just need annotated with @Document on entity